# How to open html file from another directory in mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have some html files in another directory with some javascripts, images and css. I want to use that files in my site and restrict users to access that index.html link. I used return File method in my controller action but it couldn't open images on that directory so it didn't work. What is the proper solution?Do you have an idea?

ps. (when i debugged code, i saw that js, css and html files could open with proper mime types except jpg or png files)

```
public ActionResult User(string name)
{
     string file = (Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Users/" + name)));
     string path = Path.Combine(file);
     string mime = GetMimeType(path);
     return File(path, mime);
}



public string GetMimeType(string fileName)
 {
     string mimeType = "application/unknown";
     string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
     Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext); 
     if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
      {
        mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
      }
     return mimeType;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that during the debugging process the following values are returned to the image extensions:

```
.jpg/.jpeg => mime type: image/jpeg, 
 .png => mime type:image/png
```

You can use an xml file where each file extension is mapped to its mime type. This will make sure that your system could handle all of the possible extensions. [This](http://pastebin.com/94ivivP4) link has a suggested xml file

Answer (score 0):

Better just qyery the IIS for static content mime types. That way you have a single location where to administer them.

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
//--- stuff goes on ---//


ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
var config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
var staticContent = config.GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent");
var mimeMap = staticContent.GetCollection();
var mType =mimeMap.FirstOrDefault(a => (string) a.Attributes["fileExtension"].Value == ".pdf");
return (mType == null) ? "text/plain" : mType["mimeType"];
```